# Issue networkdays value in google spreadsheet

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, days

I have created the formula = NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E84,F84) and E84 and F84 are same date -> 2022.9.5. if it is the same date in both columns, it shows the value 1 but it shows the value 0.

It worked before but now it doesn't work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dY6gwDIjjxUPTU-4v0j1MqF1sq7YCgHLTH040QMQrHU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: running `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),TODAY())` shows me `1`. can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dY6gwDIjjxUPTU-4v0j1MqF1sq7YCgHLTH040QMQrHU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ⬆I share my sheet you can enter!

Comment: =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),TODAY()) returns #ERROR on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue and now it's working properly. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/177159051?hl=en&msgid=177403678) are more details.

If you refresh the document, you can reload the function with the fix.

Comment: Seems the issue came back, not working today (08/12/2022)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a bug but here is some quick workaround:

```
=IF(A2=B2; 1; NETWORKDAYS(A2; B2))
```